# Visual Studio docker-compose is overriding container COMMAND

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile which is running LDAP:

```
FROM openjdk:8u111-jre-alpine

MAINTAINER My Name "name@example.com"

EXPOSE 10389

RUN apk add --no-cache openssl
RUN mkdir /ldap
WORKDIR /ldap
RUN wget https://github.com/kwart/ldap-server/releases/download/2016-10-04/ldap-server.jar

COPY ldap.ldif /ldap/users.ldif

CMD ["java","-jar","ldap-server.jar", "users.ldif"]
```

When I build it and run it it is working and I'm able to connect to it in .NET Core:

```
$ docker build -t myapp -f LDAP_Dockerfile .
$ docker run -it --rm -p 10389:10389 myapp
```

`docker ps` looks like this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
61116c3358c3        myapp               "java -jar ldap-serv…"   10 seconds ago      Up 9 seconds        0.0.0.0:10389->10389/tcp   dreamy_mendeleev
```

But when I run docker-compose from Visual Studio like on the pictue, I'm not able to connect:
[image]

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myapp-2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myapp2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyApp-2/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - myapp

  myapp-2_ldap:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyApp-2/LDAP_Dockerfile
    container_name: myapp_ldap
    ports:
      - 10389:10389
    networks:
      - myapp

networks:
  myapp:
    external: true
```

`docker ps` looks different now:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
15acc08715e8        myapp2:dev          "tail -f /dev/null"   11 seconds ago      Up 10 seconds       0.0.0.0:32785->80/tcp      MyApp-2_1
3b705c49e371        82beefed3363        "tail -f /dev/null"   11 seconds ago      Up 10 seconds       0.0.0.0:10389->10389/tcp   myapp_ldap
```

See the command - when running directly it is showing `java -jar ldap-serv…` but via docker compose it is showing `tail -f /dev/null`. As the error is telling `LdapException: Unable to connect to server 127.0.0.1:10389 (91)` I think this is the thing. But what is the different between running it directly via LDAP_Dockerfile and via docker compose?

**EDIT:** It is probably Visual Studio is somehow overriding the COMMAND in the container. When I copy it out and run it simply by `docker-compose up` it is working correctly.

Comment: To figure out what happens, first of all I'd suggest to inspect the image generated by `docker-compose build`: `docker history 82beefed3363 --no-trunc | less -S` then double-check the `CMD` directives, etc.

Comment: When you say "running it via Docker Compose", are you running `docker-compose up` in a terminal window, or doing something else?  (The `docker-compose.yml` doesn't override `command:` or `entrypoint:`, so the `docker ps` output is in fact pretty weird.)

Comment: @DavidMaze running it via Docker Compose means run it in Visual Studio.
@ErikMD: this command is showing for CMD this: `CMD ["java" "-jar" "ldap-server.jar" "users.ldif"]` which seems to be correct...

Comment: Please edit the question to describe exactly how you're starting the container: Docker Compose and Visual Studio are very different tools.

Comment: Well, Visual Studio is running the Docker Compose. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Ok, it is done by Visual Studio

Comment: And what happens if you choose something else than "Debug" in the first drop-down list of your vscode screenshot?